# Looping IEnumerable

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures

How do I get a specific index or loop through this data structure?

```
public class Path<TNode> : IEnumerable<TNode>
{
    public TNode LastStep { get; private set; }
    public Path<TNode> PreviousSteps { get; private set; }
    public double TotalCost { get; private set; }
    private Path(TNode lastStep, Path<TNode> previousSteps, double totalCost)
    {
        LastStep = lastStep;
        PreviousSteps = previousSteps;
        TotalCost = totalCost;
    }
    public Path(TNode start) : this(start, null, 0) { }
    public Path<TNode> AddStep(TNode step, double stepCost)
    {
        return new Path<TNode>(step, this, TotalCost + stepCost);
    }
    public IEnumerator<TNode> GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (Path<TNode> p = this; p != null; p = p.PreviousSteps)
            yield return p.LastStep;
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }

}
```

It is used as a graph for an A* algorithm. I want to do 2 things with this data structure:

1. Generate a graph (add nodes and their children)
2. Be able to traverse it and find a node and get its specific index like: `Path<Vector2> node;` then be able to do `node[0]`.

Comment: That code looks very familiar http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/04/path-finding-using-a-in-c-3-0-part-two.aspx

Comment: I think the blog was part of a 4 part series. Any chance Eric mentions what you're looking for in the rest of the series? I'll admit I'm being too lazy to look myself. I'll blame it on the holidays ;)

Comment: Its a 4 part, but he doesn't show how to generate the graph using this data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can loop through it just with a foreach loop:

```
foreach (Vector2 node in path)
{
    ...
}
```

Admittedly this looks like it will iterate in a reverse order - if you want to reverse it, you could just use LINQ like this:

```
foreach (Vector2 node in path.Reverse())
```

You can do that because you've implemented `IEnumerable<T>`. To be able to access it by index is rather trickier... you won't be able to do that in a particularly efficient way as far as I can tell.

Again, you can use LINQ to fake it - but that will just iterate over the nodes until it reaches the right element:

```
Vector2 node = path.ElementAt(2); // Or whatever
```

Comment: So can this data structure be tweaked to be more efficient in finding the index while maintaining the same functionality?

Comment: @Shawn: Well you've basically got a linked list here - and they're always good when it comes to adding/removing nodes from the start/end, and removing nodes from the middle... but generally poor at indexing. You could potentially investigate a tree-based structure or perhaps an array-based one, but while it's based on a linked list it's hard to see how it would be much more efficient.

Comment: If there are 2 child to 1 parent. How do I add those 2 child to the parent node?